# Dynamically loading TinyMCE - wrong plugin, theme paths

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

When I add the script tag `<script src="../Scripts/tinymce.min.js"></script>` to my page, TinyMCE loads fine - with plugins and theme referencing the .min versions.  However, when I remove the script tag and try loading it with jQuery, it's referencing the non-minified version, as noted in the console log.  I'm using TinyMCE v4.1.7 (2014-11-27)

```
        $.getScript('http://localhost:52417/Scripts/tinymce.min.js', function () {
            window.tinymce.dom.Event.domLoaded = true;
            tinymce.baseURL = 'http://localhost:52417/Scripts';
            tinymce.init({
                selector: '#announcementText',
                plugins: ['link image'],
                toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist | outdent indent | link image',
                menubar: false,
                statusbar: false
            });
        });
```

`GET http://localhost:52417/Scripts/themes/modern/theme.js 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:52417/Scripts/plugins/link/plugin.js 404 (Not Found) 
GET http://localhost:52417/Scripts/plugins/image/plugin.js 404 (Not Found)`

The domLoaded and baseURL lines were found from other examples on SO, and didn't make a difference. How can I get it to reference the correct path to the theme and plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I could come up with is to copy and rename the theme.min.js, and plugin.min.js files to theme.js and plugin.js and publish those along with the minified versions.

Answer (score 23):

Add `tinymce.suffix = '.min';` before invoking `tinymce.init()`

Comment: still applicable in 2021!

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to include plugins in html in `<script>` tag.

Then use some lib to pack those files into one to reduce number of requests to serwer **for example for Symfony2** (in twig template):

```
{% javascripts output='js/tinymce_plugins.js' filter='?uglifyjs2'
            '@BrokerStarCommonBundle/Resources/public/js/tinymce/themes/modern/theme.min.js'
            '@BrokerStarCommonBundle/Resources/public/js/tinymce/plugins/advlist/plugin.min.js'
            '@BrokerStarCommonBundle/Resources/public/js/tinymce/plugins/autolink/plugin.min.js'
            .............

'@BrokerStarCommonBundle/Resources/public/js/tinymce/plugins/textpattern/plugin.min.js'
            '@BrokerStarCommonBundle/Resources/public/js/tinymce/plugins/tabbutton/plugin.min.js'
            '@BrokerStarCommonBundle/Resources/public/js/tinymce/plugins/checkboxes/plugin.min.js'
            '@BrokerStarCommonBundle/Resources/public/js/tinymce/plugins/noneditable/plugin.min.js'
            %}
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
            {% endjavascripts %}
            <script>
```